# NestJs + ApplicationInsights - when deployed, correlation context not working

Tags: nestjs, azure-application-insights, azure-appservice

frustratingly,  only encounter the issue when deployed on azure app service, and have no problem on a (local) docker image or my machine.

applicationInsights has request scoped context like operation_id, parent_id, etc.
Normally, this information is passed on when logging happens

```
import * as applicationInsights from 'applicationinsights';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {

    //context is null when deployed, defined and includes operationId etc when run        //locally/on docker
    const context = applicationInsights.getCorrelationContext();

    applicationInsights.defaultClient.trackEvent({
      name: 'test',
      properties: { customProperty: 'abc' },
    });

    return 'Hello';
  }
}
```

the setup is minimal repro so I can't think of anything that'd be causing this other than some Nest - app service - app insights interaction

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const appInsightConnectionString =
    process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING;

  applicationInsights
    .setup(appInsightConnectionString)
    .setInternalLogging(true, true)
    .setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
    .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
    .setAutoCollectPerformance(true)
    .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
    .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
    .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
    .start();

  applicationInsights.defaultClient.commonProperties = {
    environment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT || 'DEFAULT',
  };

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Anyone else using appInsights for logging able to get this working? Or strategies for finding the issue here?

no middleware or networking settings added[image]

Answer (score 0):

For posterity,
the issue was with azure app service applicationInsightsAgent which seems incompatible with propagating context in NestJs async calls.
Stopping app service's appInsights agent resolved the issue

removed:

```
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_mode=default
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION=~3
```